# Conditional Statement not working in Django template while accessing a dictionary with dot operator

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-orm

I am trying to offer a download option if the file daily-yyyy-mm.csv exits but it always shows **Not Avaialable**
 even if the file exists.

I have made a dictionary (file_list) in views.py which saves True for that index if the file exists. I have checked the path generated at os.path.join and it is correct and also the dictionary has True for the files that exist. I think the problem is using 2 nested dot operators while accessing the dictionary in template.

Template

```
        {% for upload in upload_list %}
        <tr>
            {%if file_list.upload.upload_report_date %}
            <td><a href="{%static 'media/daily-{{ upload.upload_report_date|date:"Y-m" }}.csv" download >Download</a></td>

            {% else %}
            <td>Not Available</td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Views.py

```
    upload_list = Upload.objects.all().order_by('-upload_at')
    file_list={}
    for upload in upload_list:
        try:
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'daily-%s.csv' % (upload.upload_report_date).strftime("%Y-%m"))):
                file_list[upload.upload_report_date]=True
        except:
            pass
```

I am using python 2.7 and django 1.6.7 .

Comment: what's `file_list.upload.upload_report_date` when you simply render or print it in your view?

Comment: If I simply render it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently try to access the dictionary `file_list` from within your template: `file_list.uplad.upload_report_date`.

With this you will always land in `else` because you can't access it that way.
Your code tries to get the propery `upload` of `file_list` which will always return `None` since it doesn't exist.

What you could do is to create a list of the available files (since you already called your variable `_list`):

```py
file_list = []
for upload in upload_list:
    try:
        if os.path.exists(...):
            file_list.append(upload.upload_report_date)
    except:
        pass
```

Then inside your template:

```
{% if upload.upload_report_date in file_list %}
...
```